# How to add Indian Rupee Currency symbol in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to add Indian Rupee Currency Symbol Indian Rupee in Google Spreadsheet?

[image]

I tried with the following

[image: No Rupee Symbol in Google Spreadsheet]

As you can notice there is NO Indian Rupee symbol. How I can apply this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It does show the Rupee symbol for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome latest version on Windows 7 (I do not have Rupee font installed. Is this the reason?)

Answer (score 7):

Select the rows you want to change the number format
Select Format > Number > Indian Rupee symbol

[image: Check the below image]

Answer (score 3):

To select custom currency, go to Format > Number > More Formats > More Currencies...

Select your desired currency from the dialog.

[image]

Comment: The menu name has changed, now its called `Custom Currency`.

Answer (score 0):

## simply just copy rupee text and paste it

if you want to add  ₹ then just copy this text character and paste it in your  google spread sheet document. I tried and it successfully worked. [image: see in this image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes it may work in Google Doc but not in Google spreadsheet. I tried to copy the Rupee font and pasted this but still I see that rectangular symbol

Comment: You can ask about this problem in google sheet FAQs, you'll get solution. https://gsuite.google.co.in/intl/en_in/faq/sheets/